# Hide a column if the content at row 2 is not equal to 'x', 'y', or 'z'

Tags: excel, vba

How can I look for content in the second row, and if it is not a "white listed" value, hide that column?

I have to look through multiple sheets that have columns at different locations (example: sheet 1 name column is A, sheet 2 name column is B).

---

Edit: Based on @ComradeMicha's comment I put something together, I'm sure its wrong but how can I make it work?

```
Sub Demo()

Dim arr(2) As String
Dim rng As Range: Set rng = Application.Range("Data!A2:CA2")
Dim cel As Range

arr(0) = "Name"
arr(1) = "Age"
arr(2) = "Gender"

For Each cel In rng.Cells
    With cel
        If Not IsInArray(cell, arr) Then
            Columns(cel).Hidden = True
        End If
    End With
Next cel
End Sub


Private Function IsInArray(valToBeFound As Variant, arr As Variant) As Boolean
'DEVELOPER: Ryan Wells (wellsr.com)
'DESCRIPTION: Function to check if a value is in an array of values
'INPUT: Pass the function a value to search for and an array of values of any data type.
'OUTPUT: True if is in array, false otherwise
Dim element As Variant
On Error GoTo IsInArrayError: 'array is empty
    For Each element In arr
        If element = valToBeFound Then
            IsInArray = True
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next element
Exit Function
IsInArrayError:
On Error GoTo 0
IsInArray = False
End Function
```

Comment: For a non-VBA solution, copy your data and paste special -> transpose it.  Then filter on the "row" (which is now a column) for only the values you want.  Then after filtering, copy and paste-special -> transpose the data you need to wherever you need it.  Otherwise, this will probably require VBA yes.  If you're looking for a place to start, you'll need to [loop through a range of cells](http://codevba.com/excel/for_each_cell_in_range.htm#.W23FacInY1k).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick if you are only looking for those 3 key words. It's not as fast as checking an array, but you are not looping through that many columns so the difference will be extremely trivial here.

`Option Compare Text` removes the case sensitive aspect of the text comparison. In other words, the macro will assume `NAME` = `name`.
Without this `Option`, `NAME` <> `name`

```
Option Explicit
Option Compare Text

Sub HideColumns()

Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data")
Dim MyCell As Range
Dim HideMe As Range

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    For Each MyCell In ws.Range("A2:CA2")
        If MyCell = "Name" Or MyCell = "Age" Or MyCell = "Gender" Then
            If HideMe Is Nothing Then
                Set HideMe = MyCell
            Else
                Set HideMe = Union(HideMe, MyCell)
            End If
        End If
    Next MyCell

    If Not HideMe Is Nothing Then
        HideMe.EntireColumn.Hidden = True
    End If
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm gonna give this a try. In my case, I will have 14 columns that I will need to check, i was using those 3 above as an example. 
If I copy paste this code in the "View Code" => "ThisWorkbook" section, thats all I need to do? and I can use it for all work sheets?

Comment: I get  "Run-time error '9': Subscript out of range"
Any Suggestions?

Comment: Is your sheet name actually “Data”?

Comment: Oh - if none of your search words are met this will also error out. You need to test to see if union is nothing before hiding the columns. Or you can error trap when it does hide - less clean tho imo

Comment: @Alex Updated to account for possibility of nothing being found. The only other reason this will error out is if your sheet name is actually not `Data`

Comment: Thank you so much, It's Running. How can I negate this, so it hides the cell if it doesn't match? Do I need to do NOT MyCell = "name" AND NOT MyCell = "age" AND .....
Also, How can I add multiple sheets? Do I just (sheetName, sheetname, sheetName)?

Comment: Just change `=` to `<>`. Please validate the solution and clear it form the unanswered queue by clicking the check mark next to solution!

Comment: Right now it’s set to run on Data sheet. You can change that top line or loop through sheets, but that’s a different question and deserves its own post :)

Comment: How can I make this run on all sheets in the workbook?

Comment: Like I said, post that as a new question and I will see you there. That requires a different solution

Comment: If questions continuously changed here there never would be a final answer. Questions need to be static - not forever changing. Hope that makes sense to you

Comment: Makes sense. I will make it right now =)
https://stackoverflow.com/q/51813294/8854270

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need VBA to automatically hide columns based on values.

Loop through each column in Row 2 (e.g. using this: https://www.excel-easy.com/vba/examples/loop-through-defined-range.html), check if the cell value is in your whitelist (e.g. using this: https://wellsr.com/vba/2016/excel/check-if-value-is-in-array-vba/), and if it is not, hide the column:

```
Columns(i).hidden = true
```

Comment: Who's downvoting this? At least leave a comment telling me why you downvote, so I can work on improving the quality of my answers! This is very bad etiquette and discourages people from spending their valuable time offering advice in a free forum.

Comment: Yah, im confused why it got down voted... Im gonna try this

Comment: I edited my question, can you take a look at the code and help me fix it?

Comment: I guess, down-vote is because of tossing links... You could present full answer with referring to those links in the end of answer.

Comment: In this line: 

`If Not IsInArray(cell, arr) Then`

replace "cell" with "cell.value". Also, you can drop the "with" and "end with" part.

Comment: My guess is because you didn't really provide a solution, you just provided links with possible solutions. (Something people typically do in comments). The only code you provided OP already had.

Comment: Either way, thank you for the help @ComradeMicha. Spasiba!!! I would upvote but I dont have enough reputation. :'(