# Enhance code to run on all sheets in a workbook

Tags: excel

How can I change this code so it runs on all sheets of a workbook? It works well, just need it to run on all sheets. =)

```
Option Explicit
Option Compare Text

Sub HideColumns()

Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data")
Dim MyCell As Range
Dim HideMe As Range

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    For Each MyCell In ws.Range("A2:EA2")
        If MyCell <> "First Name" And MyCell <> "Age" And MyCell <> "Gender" Then
            If HideMe Is Nothing Then
                Set HideMe = MyCell
            Else
                Set HideMe = Union(HideMe, MyCell)
            End If
        End If
    Next MyCell

    If Not HideMe Is Nothing Then
        HideMe.EntireColumn.Hidden = True
    End If
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loop through sheets using `For Each` loop & reset `HideMe` to `Nothing` before moving to next sheet.

```
Option Explicit
Option Compare Text

Sub HideColumns()

Dim ws As Worksheet 'Change made here
Dim MyCell As Range
Dim HideMe As Range

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
For Each ws in Worksheets 'and here
    For Each MyCell In ws.Range("A2:EA2")
        If MyCell <> "First Name" And MyCell <> "Age" And MyCell <> "Gender" Then
            If HideMe Is Nothing Then
                Set HideMe = MyCell
            Else
                Set HideMe = Union(HideMe, MyCell)
            End If
        End If
    Next MyCell

    If Not HideMe Is Nothing Then
        HideMe.EntireColumn.Hidden = True
    End If

Set HideMe = Nothing 'and here
Next ws 'and here

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: I tried like that earlier. I tried running this code and I got "Run-time error'1004': Application-defined or object-defined error"

Comment: Updated. Needed to reset `HideMe` to nothing. Try updated code plz

Comment: Awesome, I will accept the answer  (stackoverflow said I need to wait 5 min)

Comment: I might post one more about deleting/hiding the row if the cell in Column A is empty =)

Comment: You've been so helpful, One more? =)
https://stackoverflow.com/q/51820316/8854270