# How can I update code to delete blanks to also delete a specific "string"?

Tags: excel, vba

How can I update code to delete the row if the cell in column A is Blank, to as well delete the row if the cell in column A contains the string "Gender"?

I assume I need to update: `Columns("A:A").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireRow.Delete`

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
For Each ws In Worksheets 'and here
    Columns("A:A").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireRow.Delete

    For Each MyCell In ws.Range("A2:EA2")
        If Not IsInArray(MyCell, arr) Then
            If HideMe Is Nothing Then
                Set HideMe = MyCell
            Else
                Set HideMe = Union(HideMe, MyCell)
            End If
        End If
    Next MyCell

    If Not HideMe Is Nothing Then
        HideMe.EntireColumn.Hidden = True
    End If

    Set HideMe = Nothing 'and here
Next ws 'and here
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

Comment: Delete the blanks and then loop through checking for gender or use Autofilter or Find.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it's fairly simple:

1. Loop through every worksheet
2. Determine last row (`lr`) in the current  worksheet
3. Loop through a range of cells in column A
4. If the condition is met, delete the row

> *note, this ^ is not the order in which the code executes, but top-to-bottom explanation of  code*

```
Option Explicit
Private Sub remove_blank_or_gender()

   Dim ws As Worksheet
   For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Sheets

       Dim lr As Long 'last row
       lr = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

       Dim i As Long
       For i = lr To 1 Step -1
           If IsEmpty(ws.Cells(i, 1)) Or ws.Cells(i, 1) = "Gender" Then
                ws.Rows(i).EntireRow.Delete
           End If
       Next i

    Next ws

End Sub
```

If you have any questions, let me know.

---

Also on a sidenote, please avoid pasting your entire code into your
question.  The code you post should only contain relevant information to the question as per:   [**Minimal, Complete and Verifiable
Example**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Thanks for the code. I would want it to run through all the worksheets. I guess I can pass the sheet name in as a parameter?

Comment: @Alex You could, but it's easier to utilize a simple `For Each` loop, check my edited answer (`For Each ws in ThisWorkbook.Sheets`)

Comment: @Rawrplus, this wouldn't work correct if for example two rows beneath eachother have "Gender". After the first `.Delete` it will skip the row that was initially beneath the deleted row. Rather work with an unified range and delete at once ;).

Comment: `For each` and deleting rows is a bad idea - some rows might be skipped. `For i = lr to 1 step -1` is one of possible approaches.

Comment: @JvdV yeah, fell for the oldest trick in the book *(again, sigh..)*. Somehow it didn't occur to me this could happen. Edited the code accordingly with the trusty `lr to 1` algorithm. Should be fine now

Comment: I was able to run this, but it deleted all rows.

Comment: @alex can't be. Worked fine on mine Excel. **Are you sure you didn't have the column A empty and your data in different column?**

Comment: Hmmm... It worked this time, not sure why. I re-downloaded the excel and ran it again. worked fine.... Also, decided to change delete to hide. works great. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @Alex Well, you never know. Either way, glad it helped, if you have any questions to the actual implementation, let me know.

Comment: @Rawrplus, On a sidenote; while looping through rows from lastrow back to 1 works. It takes a lot of time. My suggested method of unified range would drastically cut back runtime. For example, a workbook with one worksheet with rows 1 to 1000 in column A with 'Gender' would take close to 1 minute to run. Using Union this can be cut back to under one second. Imagine what it could achieve on a whole workbook :).

Comment: @JvdV Could you perhaps provide some resource I could look at? Wouldn't the union force you to specifically select two seperate ranges in which you would have to detect and divide them into seperate ranges based on values - thus creating further unnecessary looping on their detection? Would absolutely L-O-V-E to see this in practice if it's as effective as you describe it to be

Comment: @RawrPlus, pls see provided answer :). Your answer works, its just possitive criticism and something to talk about :)

Answer (score 2):

Hereby the options to deal with this loop:

**1).** First option is to delete row by row when criteria is met:

```
Option Explicit
Private Sub remove_blank_or_gender()

Dim StartTime As Double
Dim SecondsElapsed As Double
StartTime = Timer

Dim ws As Worksheet
For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
    Dim lr As Long 'last row
    lr = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    Dim i As Long
    For i = lr To 1 Step -1
        If IsEmpty(ws.Cells(i, 1)) Or ws.Cells(i, 1) = "Gender" Then
            ws.Rows(i).EntireRow.Delete
        End If
    Next i
Next ws

SecondsElapsed = Round(Timer - StartTime, 2)
Debug.Print SecondsElapsed

End Sub
```

Executing this code on a workbook with one worksheet with column A, rows 1-1000 all filled with the value 'Gender', will result in a runtime of:

[image]

**2).** Option two using `Union` function:

```
Option Explicit
Private Sub remove_blank_or_gender()

Dim StartTime As Double
Dim SecondsElapsed As Double
Dim RNG As Range
StartTime = Timer

Dim ws As Worksheet
For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
    Set RNG = Nothing
    Dim lr As Long 'last row
    lr = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    Dim i As Long
    For i = lr To 1 Step -1
        If IsEmpty(ws.Cells(i, 1)) Or ws.Cells(i, 1) = "Gender" Then
            If Not RNG Is Nothing Then
                Set RNG = Union(RNG, Range(ws.Cells(i, 1).Address))
            Else
                Set RNG = Range(ws.Cells(i, 1).Address)
            End If
        End If
    Next i
RNG.Rows.EntireRow.Delete
Next ws

SecondsElapsed = Round(Timer - StartTime, 2)
Debug.Print SecondsElapsed

End Sub
```

This results in a runtime of:

[image]

The code is a bit messy, but my intention was to provide the two options to show the difference in runtime :). Pls note these tests are done locally and times can vary!

Good luck!