# How could I speed up deleting columns in Excel?

Tags: c#, excel, backgroundworker

I would like to accelerate the process of deleting columns in Excel. I have 2 Excel files. Let's say data file where all data exist and the deleting column names in other file. There are many worksheets in data file some have more than 15000 columns and around 2500 rows in deleting column file. It is taking longer time to delete. My question how could I speed up the code below?

```
 private void workerdelete_DoWork(object sender, System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                totalRow = xlWorksheetdelvariable.UsedRange.Rows.Count;
                Excel.Range startCell = xlWorksheetdelvariable.Cells[2, 1];
                Excel.Range endCell = xlWorksheetdelvariable.Cells[totalRow, 1];
                Excel.Range currentRange = xlWorksheetdelvariable.get_Range(startCell, endCell).Cells;
                object[,] matrixReaddelvariable = (object[,])currentRange.Value;

                foreach (Excel.Worksheet sheet in xlWorkbookDelete.Sheets)
                {
                    xlWorksheetdelete = xlWorkbookDelete.Sheets[sheet.Index];
                    columnCount = xlWorksheetdelete.UsedRange.Columns.Count;
                    int rowCount = xlWorksheetdelete.UsedRange.Rows.Count;
                    Excel.Range startCelldelete = xlWorksheetdelete.Cells[1, 1];
                    Excel.Range endCelldelete = xlWorksheetdelete.Cells[1, columnCount];
                    Excel.Range currentRangedelete = xlWorksheetdelete.get_Range(startCelldelete, endCelldelete).Cells;
                    object[,] matrixReaddelete = (object[,])currentRangedelete.Value;
                    List<int> delCols = new List<int>();


                    for (int c = 1; c <= columnCount; c++)
                    {
                        for (int r = 1; r < totalRow; r++)
                        {
                            if (dellabel == true)
                            {
                                if (matrixReaddelete[1, c].ToString() == matrixReaddelvariable[r, 1].ToString()||matrixReaddelete[1, c].ToString().Contains("_label"))
                                {
                                    delCols.Insert(0, c);
                                    break;
                                }
                            }
                            else if(matrixReaddelete[1, c].ToString() == matrixReaddelvariable[r, 1].ToString())
                            {
                                delCols.Insert(0, c);
                                break;
                            }

                        }

                        int percentage = (c + 1) * 50 / columnCount;
                        workerdelete.ReportProgress(percentage);
                    }


                    foreach (int colIndex in delCols)
                    {
                        xlWorksheetdelete.Columns[colIndex].Delete();

                        int percentage = 50 + ( delCols.IndexOf(colIndex) + 1 ) * 50 / delCols.Count;
                        workerdelete.ReportProgress(percentage);
                    }
                }


            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                System.Windows.MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }

        }
```

Comment: Neither of the excel file formats is really meant for such operations. I don't think you can achieve considerable performance increase in general. Depending on the ratio of dropped and remaining data recreating the worksheet might help. But barely.

Comment: Can't help you with the c# part, as I have no experience in that. But I do have experience with VBA and know that if you can make use of `.Union` function through c# and delete a range at once you can save tons of time. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51820316/how-can-i-update-the-code-to-delete-blanks-and-a-specific-string/51821870#51821870) is an example of what I meant. Maybe it's helpfull, maybe not. :)

Comment: First do not use the Interop library it is very slow.

Comment: It is probably shaving of time instead of huge improvements but you can try to eliminate the ToString operations to only do them once. Your `matrixReaddelvariable` could be a `string [,]` and in your loop introduce a scope local var that holds `matrixReaddelete[1,c].ToString()` and do the comparisons with that local var.